# Como persistir classe abstrata com JPA

Tags: java, banco-de-dados, hibernate, jpa

Eu conheço `JPA` e tenho outras tabelas já implementadas e funcionando.

Gostaria de saber como faço para persistir as classes abaixo, visto uma ser classe abstrata e a outra estar "extendendo" ela.

Devo colocar anotações e propriedades como se elas fossem classes 1 para N?

Se eu der `persist()` no Carro vai salvar as propriedades do Veiculo também?

```
public abstract class Veiculo {
    private int idVeiculo;
    public int getIdVeiculo() {
        return idVeiculo;
    }
    public void setIdVeiculo(int idVeiculo) {
        this.idVeiculo = idVeiculo;
    }
}
```

-

```
public class Carro extends Veiculo {
    private String marca;
    public String getMarca() {
        return marca;
    }
    public void setMarca(String marca) {
        this.marca = marca;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se você procura por uma estratégia de mapeamento com uma única tabela (ou seja, em que existe uma única tabela para `Carro` contendo também as colunas definidas em `Veiculo`) tudo o que você tem que fazer é anotar `Veiculo` com [@MappedSuperclass](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/MappedSuperclass.html).

Se você realmente quiser considerar a classe Veículo como uma entidade (ou seja, se você quiser fazer consultas polimórficas com `Veiculo`) também é possível anotar a classe abstrata com `@Entity` normalmente (veja a [seção sobre herança](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/persistence-intro002.htm) no Tutorial oficial do Java EE). A superclasse `Veiculo` também deve receber a anotação [Inheritance](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/Inheritance.html). Com essa configuração é possível persistir a classe conforme a melhor estratégia para o seu caso:

- **`SINGLE_TABLE`**: Persiste tudo em uma única tabela. Essa tabela contém colunas para todos os atributos de todas as subclasses de `Veiculo` (além dos atributos definidos em `Veiculo`). Atributos que pertencem as demais subclasses além daquela persistida ficam nulos. Uma coluna discriminadora é utilizada para diferenciar uma classe da outra.
- **`JOINED`**: Tabela para `Veiculo` separada da tabela para `Carro`. `PK` de Carro é `FK` para Veículo.
- **`TABLE_PER_CLASS`**: Cada subclasse de `Veiculo` contém sua própria tabela. Os atributos de `Veiculo` são copiados para todas as subclasses. A diferença entre essa estratégia e `@MappedSuperclass` é que alguns *providers* JPA permitem consultas polimórficas utilizando `UNION`.